# php wont give download link feedback after upload done

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to get DropzoneJS to work, i got far but it seems i've got a problem i can't solve.

so basicly what i want is to upload a file and get a download link back within the same page.

so i added this code to my index.php:

```
<form action="index.php" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

and the php code into the index.php:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$dirname = uniqid();
mkdir( $filedir.'/'.$dirname);
    mkdir( $filedir.'/'.$dirname.'/file');

copy("template/d.php", "d/$dirname/index.php");
    copy("template/dl.php", "d/$dirname/dl.php");

preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)$/', $_FILES['file']['name'], $matches);

if(in_array(strtolower($matches[1]), $accepted)) {

    if($_FILES['file']['size'] <= $maxsize) {

        $newname = ($_FILES['file']['name']);

        // file name encryption
        //$newname = md5_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']).'.'.$matches[1];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filedir.'/'.$dirname.'/file/'.$newname);

        $linkurl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].preg_replace('/\/([^\/]+?)$/', '/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'#'.$newname;

        $imgurl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].preg_replace('/\/([^\/]+?)$/', '/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).$filedir.'/'.$dirname.'/file/'.$newname;
        $alt = $_POST["alt"];
    $dlurl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].preg_replace('/\/([^\/]+?)$/', '/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).$filedir.'/'.$dirname;

        print '<h2>Picture Uploaded Successfuly!!!!</h2> <p id="codes">

      <img src="'.$imgurl.'" height="300" alt="Uploaded Picture" >

        <label for="codebb">BBCode:</label>
        <input type="text" id="codebb" value="[URL='.$siteurl.'][IMG]'.$dlurl.'[/IMG][/URL]" onclick="javascript:this.focus();this.select();" readonly="true" /><br />
        <label for="codehtml">HTML Code: </label>
        <input type="text" id="codehtml" value=\'&lt;a href="'.$siteurl.'"&gt;&lt;img src="'.$dlurl.'" alt="'.$alt.'" /&gt;&lt/a&gt;\' onclick="javascript:this.focus();this.select();" readonly="true" /><br />
        <label for="codedirect">Direct Link:</label>
        <input type="text" id="codedirect" value="'.$dlurl.'" onclick="javascript:this.focus();this.select();" readonly="true" /></p>';

        echo ".$newname";
    } else 

        print '<p>Sorry, Max Picture size is 10Mb</p>';

}
}

?>
```

when i upload the file the php works and the file is uploaded successfully into its folder so the php is working.

my problem now is why dont i get the print from the php script.

fully working script:

```
http://37.34.62.131/test/uploader%201.0/
```

not working NEW script:

```
http://37.34.62.131/test/
```

i think it has something to do with the uploader because my old script uses a submit button and my newer version is using a automatic submit.

i very appreciate your time!

Comment: i could send you my source files.

Comment: if i use the forse fallback option its working like a sharm! still dont have any clue why the script isnt working without the drag and drop!